# How to deserialize accented chars (é, ü, ..) correctly using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject?

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

Accents like é, ü etc. exist in my JSON file but are not parsing correctly in Unity using Newtonsoft.Json.

For example, my fileName contains JSON: {"itemLabel": "Henri Poincaré"},{"itemLabel": "Aristotle"} .. etc

This script then populates a simple list of class Human:
var humans = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List>(File.ReadAllText(fileName));

Normal English chars "Aristotle" work fine and my Unity scene works nice. But accents fail. For e.g. Unity renders "Henri Poincar�" instead of "Henri Poincaré", "Johann Helfrich von M�ller" instead of "Johann Helfrich von Müller", etc.

Why aren't these automatically understood because Notepad recognizes them without any trouble?
As a beginner I searched online for a solution and looked at the docs to identify if there were Settings I could pass but didn't find anything clear https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm

Do you have suggestions for how to resolve?

Thank you

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` does not have problems deserializing these characters - it's more likely to do with the encoding of your file you are trying to read. What is it saved as? Alternatively, try explicitly specifying the encoding on your `File.ReadAllText`

Comment: Notepad applies some heuristics to detect the file's encoding; .NET code assumes Unicode and only tries to guess based on a byte order mark. Your file is likely encoded as Windows-1252, so either use the overload that allows you to pass in an encoding, or save it again as UTF-8 (which is the "default" encoding for .NET and a sensible choice in general).

Comment: Maybe your font atlas is missing those characters hence the ? rendering

Comment: When getting question mark in triangle it is probably the font that is wrong.  Try a different font.  Inside VS you may need to change the default font while debugging.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your suggestions. The .json file was already encoded in UTF-8.  The solution, as @Everts suggested, was to create a new Font Asset with Character Set set to "Extended ASCII" 

Comment: Just for the sake of extra info, Extended ASCII may generate a larger than needed font atlas. What is usually done is collecting all the characters that will be needed (from localization files that is) and then generate the atlas with only the needed characters.